# Creating a list of repetitions from a table

Tags: r, list

I want to create a table with two columns, the first column is a number, the second columns is the repetitions of different strings, from a table with the number of repetitions of each string.

I mean:

**1/ I have this:**

A 1,3     *#("A" From 1 to 3)*

B 4,5

C 6,9

...

**2/ I want this:**

1 A

2 A

3 A

4 B

5 B

6 C

7 C

8 C

9 C
...

Thanks

Comment: Hello Francisco, welcome to SO. You put your question clearly. However, it is still difficult to answer it. What exactly are the data structures you are using? Your tags say `list`. In your question you say `table`. If you could give us the data samples in a format R can read on our own systems, we can help find a solution. But without know the exact data structure it is hard and involves a lot of guessing.

Answer (score 0):

We can split the 'col2' at the `,`, create a sequence by looping over the `list` and converting to `numeric`, then `unnest` the 'col2'

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
   mutate(col2 = map(strsplit(col2, ","), ~ {
          x1 <- as.numeric(.x)
           x1[1]:x1[2]})) %>%
    unnest(c(col2))
# A tibble: 9 x 2
#  col1   col2
#  <chr> <int>
#1 A         1
#2 A         2
#3 A         3
#4 B         4
#5 B         5
#6 C         6
#7 C         7
#8 C         8
#9 C         9
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(col1 = c('A', 'B', 'C'),
     col2 = c('1,3', '4,5','6,9'), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
df <- data.frame(
  V1 = LETTERS[1:3],
  V2 = c("1,3", "4,5", "6,9")
)

split_idx <- strsplit(df$V2, ",") # split V2 into two parts
split_idx <- t(list2DF(split_idx)) # puts the values column wise 

split_idx <- apply(split_idx, 2, as.numeric)

colnames(split_idx) <- c("from", "to") # e.g., in "1,3", 1 would be `from`, and 3 is `to`. 

df <- data.frame(df, split_idx)

out <- list()

for (i in seq_along(df$V1)) {
  out[[i]] <- c(df[["V1"]][[i]], rep(
    df[[1]][[i]],
    df[["to"]][[i]] - df[["from"]][[i]]
  ))
}

V1 = unlist(out)

 df <- data.frame(V1, idx = seq_along(V1))
```